# i have to send multiple images via bluetooth .but how to show progressbar when image send one by one in my application

Tags: java, android

This is my  code.

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    mul = fileSelectorList;
     Log.d("final",""+mul);
    int length = mul.size();

    Intent mail_int = new Intent();
    mail_int.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    mail_int.setType("image/*");
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        File file = new File(mul.get(i));
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
    }
    mail_int.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    startActivity(mail_int);
```

when images start to send i have to show progress bar to send image one by one.How it is possible.

Comment: Doesn't look like C to me... This is Java.

Comment: I have to use this code to sending the images files via Bluetooth.but when i have to send file i have to set one dailogbox in tital images and progress bar to send the images. how it is possible can anybody tell me.